# How to send invitation to join my website to users Facebook friends.

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Edit:
I am developing social website using ASP.NET MVC.
Where user can log in with Facebook or using my website registration.
I am using Facebook api to authenticate Facebook user and can retrieve his friend list. 
Now I want to send notification to his friends when user wants to invite them to my website.

Like candy crush sends notification to all his Facebook friends.

Though candy crush is Facebook game, can we similarly send notification in my website?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello respected people, people are answering my question and also I have edited it to make it more readable. Please remove hold and please let me know your thoughts if you think it is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/notifications

> Currently, only apps on Facebook.com can use App Notifications.
>   Notifications are only surfaced on the desktop version of
>   Facebook.com.

Candy Crush is a Facebook game, it does not work for external Websites. The Notification system is built for Facebook Notifications, not to invite someone to an external Website. The only serious way to invite someone to your Website is to use the Send Dialog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/send-dialog

Also, you can only send Notifications to Users who authorized your App, of course.

Comment: Is it possible to edit "to" field and send it to multiple people? Thanks

Comment: you can only specify one friend/id, multiple are not possible